# How to subtract consecutive even rows from odd rows in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I have the following snapshot of the mysql table.

```
ID      NAME          TIME                     TYPE      
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 08:10:04.000000       0   
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 10:10:55.000000       1  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 10:15:31.000000       0  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 11:15:50.000000       1  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 11:49:21.000000       0  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 12:13:02.000000       1  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 12:14:26.000000       0  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 13:14:33.000000       1  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 13:21:26.000000       0  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 13:51:43.000000       1  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 13:53:29.000000       0  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 15:44:45.000000       1  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 15:46:25.000000       0  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 16:45:44.000000       1  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 17:01:58.000000       0  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 18:07:18.000000       1  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 18:09:00.000000       0  
911018  AAA 2016-11-07 19:15:33.000000       1
```

`TYPE 0` indicates **IN** 
`TYPE 1` indicates **OUT**

Is there a way to subtract the 2nd row with 1st row(2-1) and 4th row with 3rd row(4-3) and so on.. Then I could to add that and store it in same table or other table maybe (2nd row - 1st row)+(4th row - 3rd row)+(6th row -5th row)so on, it should do it only when the Type is in the pair 0,1,0,1,0,1...

If the pair is 0,0,1,0,1,0... then it should take the the first one similarly IF the pair is 0,1,0,1,1,0,1.. then it should take the 2nd 1

The result would be something like

```
911018 AAA 2016-11-07 02:00:00.000000 (10:10:04.0000000 - 08:00:00.000000)
911018 AAA 2016-11-07 01:00:00.000000 (11:15:00.0000000 - 10:15:00.000000)
911018 AAA 2016-11-07 00:24:00.000000
911018 AAA 2016-11-07 01:00:00.000000
....
```

Then maybe a table having the (sum of the time) row like

```
911018 AAA 2016-11-07 09:30:00.00000
```

Hope I have explained it in an understandable way.

Comment: There are no even or uneven rows in context of SQL.

Comment: I can tell you you'll save a lot of trouble if you can process this data in a procedural way rather than trying to make SQL do it.  I'll write up an answer addressing how SQL might address this, but I can't guarantee I'll get it 100% as this just isn't a good task for SQL processing

Comment: Per my previous comment: I see you're using mySql; that makes things worse, because the tricks you'd use depend heavily on windowed functions (which, it seems, don't exist in mySql).  So sorry - I'll stick with "you really don't want to do this in SQL in my opinion"

Comment: Thank you frlan and Mark Adelsberger.

Comment: Luckily, the sequence is always 0,1,0,1,0,1. So there's nothing to worry about.What does "10:10:04" represent in your data set? What's your PRIMARY KEY? And are there any rows with an id of 911018 but with a name other than 'AAA'?

Comment: 10:10:14 represents Time stored in datetime format and there are no primary keys and there are id's other than 911018 and 911018 ids are also there with different dates like 2016-10-05,2016-11-09. I am selecting Time based on date range.

Comment: No. Not much of that made any sense. I asked about '10:10:04'. Relational data should ALWAYS have a PK. Incidentally, when replying to a comment, include the name of the commentator to which you are responding (e.g. "@Strawberry")

Answer (score 0):

i tested my previous awser and fixed a few things.

```
select e.id, e.name, e.time, e.type, o.time, (o.time - e.time) test, cast((o.time - e.time) as time ) as test2
from Table1 e
left join Table1 o on o.time = (

    select min(time) from Table1 where (time > e.time) and (type=1)
)

where e.type=0
```

still missing the gaps in odd and even but its close

---

i did not test this, but something like this ( might needs tweaking ):

```
select id, name, (e.time - o.time) as time 
from you_sql_table e
left join you_sql_table o ON (e.type=0) and e.time = (select min(time)
from your_sql_table where (type=1) and (time > e.time))
```

the trick is to select the next value in the join with the select query on the same table. 
you can mix values from the main select query.

the example below runs on mysql 
carfuel example:

```
SELECT `n`.`id`, `c`.`current` AS `previous`, `n`.`current` 
(IFNULL(n.current,0)-c.current) AS `dist`, `n`.`fuel cost` 
(IFNULL(n.current,0)-c.current)/n.`fuel cost` AS `km per euro`,
`n`.`date`, `n`.`rate` FROM `carfuel` AS `c` 
LEFT JOIN `carfuel` AS `n` ON n.current = (select min(current) 
from carfuel where current > c.current) 
WHERE ((IFNULL(n.current,0)-c.current)>0) 

id = just a record id
current = the km setting of my car at the moment i filled up my car 
fuel cost = the amount i payed to fill up my car. 
date = the date i filled up my car ( not needed ) 
rate = rate of fuel price ( not needed )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you yo make a new field in the table, with "pairID" for each in, out, so you can group by pairID, order by time, and diff the dates.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question I would do it like this.

```
with a as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [id] DESC) AS RowNumber,  
    [name],
    [id],
    [time],

FROM [YourTable] 
)
select * from a where RowNumber % 2 = 1
```

for odd numbers or

```
select * from a where RowNumber % 2 = 0
```

for even.